# colorbox not showing content correctly

Tags: jquery, jsp, colorbox

I want to create/test a simple popup based on colorbox plugin. I have a simple possible html page without any extra css just jquery, colorbox and colorbox.css but not sure why popup is not shown correctly. You can try the page here http://goo.gl/VWQRC

After clicking on Problem loggin in? link I am getting this in chrome
[image]

here is my js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Using a jQuery object:
    var $p = $("#reset-popup");
    $("#problem-link").colorbox({inline:true, href:$p});

});
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It seems the size of the colorbox is defined to be too way too small. By what I can't fathom though

Answer (score 1):

Try specifiying the colorbox `width` option like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Using a jQuery object:
    var $p = $("#reset-popup");
    $("#problem-link").colorbox({
          inline: true, 
          width: "50%",
          href: $p
    });
});
```

E.g. this markup contains the hidden content (#reset-popup) for inline calls:

```
<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='reset-popup' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
         <p><strong>This content comes from a hidden element on this page.</strong></p>                     
    </div>
</div>
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/WGTVY/

Comment: It should be something else. Like additional styles on a page. Your page it works even if no width specified: http://jsfiddle.net/WGTVY/1/

Comment: Most possibly the page is missing some additional styles. I've checked with the [OP's sandbox](http://goo.gl/VWQRC), seems like the colorbox popup div element with id `#reset-popup` is not included??

Comment: OK I found the problem. I was using jquery v1.4 :| ... using v1.8 fixed the problem

Comment: You could post your finding as an answer, it can help others just as much in future :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use another colorbox.css (or maybe even another version of colorbox). Yours looks to be for a different version or what. You may try to use styles and JS used by [chridam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122005/chridam) in his example (from v1.3.16).

Besides, it has nothing common with styles, but this `href:$p` looks to be a wrong code. Actually, you do not need it at all as colorbox should take clicked link href and find your `#reset-popup` using it. And you are giving a link to div object wraped with jquery instead of   a string with link/selector.

As I can see from test page resulting width of `#cboxContent`, `#cboxTopCenter` and `#cboxBottomCenter` is the same as `#cboxWrapper`'s width, when it should be less than that in order to left a space for `#cboxMiddleLeft` and `#cboxMiddleRight`. If I change width of those three elements to smaller one, I'm getting almost correct colorbox. For me it looks like some different styles are expected by that version of colorbox.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I was using jquery v1.4.2. and thats not compatible with colorbox. I used the latest one from jquery.com (v1.8.2) Now its working fine. You dont need to set width of the popup in settings.